# Is there any 'for + NP + to-infinitive' where the NP is not the semantic subject of the infinitive?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, infinitive-constructions

In (a), for example, *you* is the semantic subject of *apologize*:

> a. I've been waiting for you to apologize.

Is there any `for + NP + to-infinitive` where the NP is not the semantic subject of the infinitive?

Comment: Obviously, there are passive examples where the NP is not the **non-agentive**: 'We've been waiting for the new song to be released'.

Comment: @Araucaria Where do you get your definition of 'semantic subject'? 'The new song' is  certainly the 'syntactic subject'. I think OP might be better using the 'agent' terminology here.

Comment: But that's almost certainly not what OP intends. 'Good for your health/mind/eyes/skin/heart/mood/wallet ... ' are obviously [adj + adjective complement], not part of a [for + NP + to-inf] construct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry if the way the OP was presented was confusing to you, but Araucaria's example _It is good for your health to eat vegetables_ is the kind of example I was looking for.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks for the example and the paper. Looks to be quite helpful.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I've got a question about the paper. Aarts seems to consider 'NP + to-infinitive' as a non-finite clause (e.g., 'you to apologize'). But 'NP + to-infinitive' cannot function as a subject, a predicative complement, or an absolute construction. For example, *_You to apologize is necessary._ *_The expectation is you to apologize._  *_You to apologize, you must first admit you were wrong._ How come a non-finite clause cannot function as a subject, a predicative complement, or an absolute construction?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Come to think of it, you're right. Perhaps this issue is way out of my league. What you say Aarts would presumably say, though, sounds more like what CamGEL's authors would presumably say, because the latter, but not the former, are the ones who classify _for_ as comparable to _that_. Also, _What we need is you to be there_ doesn't work for me. Only _What we need is for you to be there_ does.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, I find the paper quite useful and informative with all the analyses but without getting too technical. One thing, though, is that Aarts seems to do without the subject-to-object raising, if I have read the paper correctly. That's quite a surprise, unless of course he has been against raising all along, which I don't know. // FWIW, I can be comfortable with the last sentence, but not the second one.

Comment: What happened to @Araucaria’s side of the conversation?

Answer (score 0):

"Subject" is a syntactic and not a semantic function. If you are talking about semantic roles, in your example "you" is a potential undergoer who is expected to perform something.  In a sentence such as: "it was hard for him to leave", instead, "him" encodes an experiencer.

Comment: There are deeper analyses which precise the terms 'semantic subject' etc. But here, it seems clear that 'thematic role' is intended.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could you please provide a brief reference?

Comment: Offhand, [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASubject_(grammar)) gives a brief overview, but you really need to do some research and look for relevant papers. Note that different grammarians suggest differing analyses / terminologies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth As you can read in the entry, this notion is very problematic because it obscures different semantic roles. I can't see its usefulness.

Comment: It provides a term for use in imperatives such as "Go home!" where the 'understood subject' 'You' has been called the '_semantic subject_'. See [Syntactic Argumentation & the Structure of English_Perlmutter et al](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ADUa3a-u7UkC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22semantic+subject%22+imperative&source=bl&ots=riocKKNSQp&sig=ACfU3U2HWay9BlW3tJhjNAfekLJdD5dTEA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7kvzrj8foAhUZQRUIHcVEDlgQ6AEwAnoECAYQKA#v=onepage&q=%22semantic%20subject%22%20imperative&f=false). But please do further research yourself. The term 'semantic subject' is known, and used by some.